# android animation not workin

Tags: java, android, animation

i have a simple project to testing anmiation effects on a button but it not workin !! when i press the button noting works , what is wrong ?can any body test it in his system ?(maybe my emulator has a problem ! ) this is my MainActivity.java codes

```
package com.behnam.temp.mainPackage;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn_1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_button);
            btn_1.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });

}
```

}

and i have placed an xml android file to res/anim with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemos.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:duration="5000"         
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

strt the animation using the view,

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_button);
        arg0.startAnimation(anim);
        }
```

Comment: You are using the button object in your code and view is needed
can you please try this link:
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html

you can use rotate alone form the post.

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem !

the animation didn't work just for xmlns link wrong !
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is true
not "http://schemos.android.com/apk/res/android"